# Negative reputation turning into positive reputation can anyone else verify this?

Tags: bug

This occurs if deleting a post with negative reputation. I logged in another browser different machine it stays that way.

Comment: The notification box shows positive changes in reputation since the last time you opened it. If you gained 15 rep from a question being deleted, it's going to notify you that you gained 15 rep. that's not a bug

Comment: Finding the answer to this question in that answer is somewhat complicated as the only part that explains deleted post behavior is in the "auditing" section and the OP here has made no indication that they're looking at their reputation history page to see the terminology there. That answer seems very similar to the MSE FAQ and may benefit from being updated to explain this in more detail.

Comment: Please don't deface your questions. Duplicate questions serve a purpose, and drastically editing them defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not turning into positive reputation, it's just refunded to you.

When you are downvoted you lose reputation. Deleting that post makes the votes go away in most cases. So, when you delete, you are credited back the reputation you lost. This works both ways. Deleting an upvoted post will cause you to *lose* any reputation you gained from the upvotes.

If, however, you undelete the post, you will lose/regain the reputation again as the votes are tallied anew.

You can find more information about this on the [Meta Stack Exchange FAQ about reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work/7238#7238). The part that relates to your question is here, under the "Additionally" section:

> Deleting and undeleting posts may reverse reputation effects as well, if these posts have votes. Actions previously taken on deleted posts cease to affect reputation within five minutes ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/recent-reputation-history-changes)), unless the post meets both the following criteria (in which case the reputation effects will be permanent) ([source](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/)):
>
> - The post had a score of at least +3
> - The post has been visible on the site for at least 60 days